# Emit hidden cell while looping using .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) property

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to put filter on the table which should return only one entry with goal to capture that entry row number. To achieve that I am trying to loop through range using `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` property, however during my test I find out that loop still goes through all range, but always returns only visible cell row.

For example: I have table with 14 entries + heading row with filtered visible entry at 9th row. My code below returns 15 results, but `rw.Row` always `9`. How to truly limit loop only to visible cells?

```
Sub Test()

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Test_TBL")


    With tbl
        'sets filter criteria
        .Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Specific Name" 
        .Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="Specific Number" 
        
        'readjust range to emit headings row
        With .AutoFilter.Range
            Set AutoFilterRange = .Resize(.Rows.count - 1, .Columns.count).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)              
            'in theory, only one (visible) record should be available for loop
            For Each rw In AutoFilterRange
                    Debug.Print rw.Row
                    counter = counter + 1
                    Debug.Print counter
            Next
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`For Each rw In AutoFilterRange` loops through all **cells** of `AutoFilterRange` because it defaults to `AutoFilterRange.Cells` and not through all **rows** which would mean `AutoFilterRange.Rows`.

Further `AutoFilterRange` can be a **discontinous** range that can consist of multiple areas. So you need to loop through all areas and through all rows in each area, to get all rows in a discontinous range.

```
Dim Ar As Range
For Each Ar In AutoFilterRange.Areas  ' loop through areas
    Dim Rw As Range
    For Each Rw In Ar.Rows  ' loop through rows in each area
        Debug.Print Rw.Row  ' return row number
    Next Rw
Next Ar
```